# Dash - Interval() output not visible

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I am using Dash - Plot.ly to create a Dashboard, which needs to be updated every 30 seconds. I found that dcc.interval() would do the task, but when I am trying to callback it only updates once and then code stays in that static state forever.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


@app.callback(
    Output("table-id", "children"),
    Input("interval-component", "n_intervals"),
)

csv_path = 'C:/Users/(username)/OneDrive/Back/data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

def update_table_content(n):
    # Update your table content generation logic here
    updated_table_children = [
        html.Tr([
            html.Th("Product", style=header_style),
            html.Th("High", style=header_style),
            html.Th("Low", style=header_style),
            html.Th("Live", style=header_style),
            html.Th("Range", style=header_style)
        ]),
        *[
            html.Tr([
                html.Td(df.loc[i, 'Product Name'], style=content_style),
                html.Td(style=content_style),
                html.Td(style=content_style),
                html.Td(df.loc[i, 'Live Sum'], style=content_style),
                html.Td(style=content_style)
            ]) for i in range(len(df) - 1)
        ]
    ]
    print(f"updated table {dt.datetime.utcnow()}")

    return updated_table_children
```

HTML Division used in app layout:

```
html.Div(
            style=container_style,
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    id = 'division1',
                    style=division1_style,
                    children=[
                        dcc.Interval(id  = 'interval-component', interval = 30000),
                        html.Table(
                            id = 'table-id',
                            style=table_style,
                            children=update_table_content(0)
                        ),
                        html.H3(children = f"Last Update on {currentTime}")
                    ],
                ),
```

I have tried printing the time the code is being update both in console and the HTML
but I found that the the code is being updated perfectly at the stated time interval but the output is not being updated with that

for example I am attaching 2 images depicting the output of the print statements

[This is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVZEZ.png)

[This is the output in the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l03on.png)